# Switching between windows doesn't work in some apps

Tags: macos, keyboard, switching

(using OSX 10.6.4 if that matters)

I know about the <kbd>Cmd-`</kbd>, but it doesn't work everywhere, namely Chrome and Firefox don't seem to react to it. It works in, for example, Finder and OpenOffice.

Any solution to this problem?

Comment: It works fine for me in both Chrome 12.0.742.112 and Firefox 4.01, the current standard builds, under Snow Leopard. Perhaps it's due to having to run older versions under Tiger.

Comment: It's Snow Leopard here as well, Chrome 14 and FF 5.

Comment: Oops, misread, thought you wrote 10.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Places to check for things intercepting the keystroke:

1. **Browser Extensions**: Perhaps the same extension on both browsers
2. **Macro App**: TextExpander or Keyboard Maestro, for example
3. **Services Shortcut**: In the *Chrome* or *Firefox* menu choose *Services* then *Services Preferences...*. Scroll to the *Internet* section and see if anything is set up to use the <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>`</kbd> shortcut.
4. **Application Shortcuts**: In that same dialog (or choose *Keyboard* in the *System Preferences* click *Application Shortcuts* in the left pane and see if there are any custom shortcuts for Chrome and Firefox that use that combination.

Comment: Checked 1, 3 and 4, nothing suspicious. I have no idea what macro apps are though.

Comment: @Mladen Well, you would have had to intentionally installed one. TextExpander replaces text you type with other text in quite sophisticated ways. Keyboard Maestro lets you assign more complex macro actions -- click here, copy, change apps, click there, paste, etc. -- to keystrokes. They're both examples of apps that could be intercepting your keystroke.

Comment: I don't think that I have anything similar installed. Thanks for trying to help, anyway. Just noticed that Adium has the same problem.

Comment: Oh, found it. It was just mapped as some other key combination. :( Resetting default settings solved the issue.